# configure JSR45 on intellij with JDK1.5 and JBOSS EAP6.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, java-ee-5

How with Intellij ultimate 2020 could i using JSR45 option on JDK1.5 project with JBOSS EAP 6.4 and EJB2.
Currently JSP debug option is not active
Regards

Comment: Did you try JBoss run/debug configuration instead?

Comment: When i tried to add an breakpoint in javacode contains in JSP page, Breakpoint Line is disabled, I could not activate it